# Помогите разжевать теорию (аргументы по умолчанию)

Tags: javascript

**Есть задача**

```
function showMessage(from, text = anotherFunction()) {
  // anotherFunction() выполнится только если не передан text
  // результатом будет значение text
}
```

**Вот к ней теория**

Вычисление параметров по умолчанию
В JavaScript параметры по умолчанию вычисляются каждый раз, когда функция вызывается без соответствующего параметра.
В приведённом выше примере, функция `anotherFunction()` не будет вызвана вообще, если указан параметр text.
С другой стороны, функция будет независимо вызываться каждый раз, когда text отсутствует.

**Вопрос**

1. (`anotherFunction()` выполнится только если не передан text.)
   Тут я вообще не понял куда `text` должен быть не передан чтоб выполнилась `anotherFunction`.
2. (результатом будет значение `text`)
   Тут я так понимаю значиние которое записано в аргументе.
3. (В JavaScript параметры по умолчанию вычисляются каждый раз, когда функция вызывается без соответствующего параметра.) Как я понимаю параметр по умолчанию указывается если я не указываю значение в аргументе, НО зачем мне тогда значение по умолчанию которое будет автоматически выполнятся которе не указано в параметр функции чтоб вызвать её без соответствующего параметра.
4. (В приведённом выше примере, функция `anotherFunction()` не будет вызвана вообще, если указан параметр text.) К примеру если мне нужно вычислить `calcSumm` я могу в параметр  `num1 = 1` добавить по умолчанию, и провести с ним какие-то манипуляции, а почему здесь это не работает, если можете подскажите где почитать.
5. (С другой стороны, функция будет независимо вызываться каждый раз, когда `text` отсутствует.) Также здесь, я так понял имеется в ввиду `anotherFunction()` но как он будет вызван при отсутствии `text` он не сможет быть присвоен в `text` по умолчанию.

Учусь по learn.javascript.ru - Основы JavaScript - Функции, подскажите пожалуйста может где это более разжовано бо прочитал уже раз 10 и не понимаю...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Параметры по умолчанию для аргументов функций были добавлены в стандарт ECMAScript 2015 (ES6)

```
function greet(name = 'Гость') {
  console.log(`Привет, ${name}!`);
}

greet('Анна'); // Привет, Анна!
greet(); // Привет, Гость!
```

До версии ES6, для установки значений по умолчанию использовался оператор || (ИЛИ)

```
function greet(name) {
  name = name || 'Гость';
  console.log(`Привет, ${name}!`);
}

greet('Анна'); // Привет, Анна!
greet(); // Привет, Гость!
```

Также можно использовать условие для значений по умолчанию в функции

```
function greet(name) {
  if (name === undefined) {
    name = 'Гость';
  }
  console.log(`Привет, ${name}!`);
}

greet('Анна'); // Привет, Анна!
greet(); // Привет, Гость!
```

Comment: Очень классное пояснение, спасибо)

Answer (score 3):

Первым делом кратко про параметры по умолчанию:

Допустим у нас имеется функция

```js
function f(arg = 5) { console.log(arg); }
```

Её можно вызвать двумя способами:

```js
f() // 5
f(3) // 3
```

Таким образом можно сделать вывод, что если в функцию не передан аргумент, то аргумент примет стандартное указанное значение (в вашем случае это результат функции, которая будет вызываться каждый раз, когда надо получить стандартное значение для этого аргумента).

Отвечаю на вопросы:

> `anotherFunction()` выполнится только если не передан text

Если мы не передаём параметр, то (как уже упоминалось выше) передаётся параметр по умолчанию, а так как параметр по умолчанию в данном случае это выражение, которое вызывает функцию, то параметром по умолчанию каждый раз будет новое значение, которое вернула функция.
Если же мы всё же передадим параметр, то аргумент по умолчанию использоваться не будет (вместо него будет использоваться переданный нами аргумент), следовательно функция не будет вызвана.

> результатом будет значение `text`

Да, верно. Если мы не передаём аргумент, то text будет являться значением по умолчанию (которое вернула функция при вызове этого метода). Однако если мы передадим туда например строку `abc`, то результатом уже будет сама строка `abc`

> зачем мне тогда значение по умолчанию которое будет автоматически выполнятся которое не указано в параметр функции чтоб вызвать её без соответствующего параметра?

Для удобства. Допустим у нас есть

```js
function log(text, loglevel) { //... }
```

Где функция log сохраняет данные для отладки. Уровень предупреждения (инфо, предупреждение, ошибку) можно передать как параметр loglevel.

Так как данная функция будет использоваться часто, и в основном для логирования уровня info, то каждый раз прописывать `log("Value a is...", LogLevelType.info)` слишком долго и не удобно. Поэтому мы можем объявить метод как

```js
function log(text, loglevel=LogLevelType.info) { //... }
```

И тогда для логирования уровня info можно будет просто прописать `log("Value a is...")`. И в случае, если мы захотим залогировать ошибку, то мы всё ещё можем вручную указать параметр: `log("Fatal error! ...", LogLevelType.error)`

> В приведённом выше примере, функция `anotherFunction()` не будет вызвана вообще, если указан параметр `text`.

В данном случае имеется ввиду, что если аргумент `text` передан (например вызов `showMessage(0, "Hello")`), то тогда значение переменной `text` будет как раз таки равен строке `Hello`, а не результату `anotherFunction()`.

> как он будет вызван при отсутствии text он не сможет быть присвоен в text по умолчанию.

Почему не сможет? Если вы например не передали строку `Hello` (`showMessage(0)`), то тогда значение переменной `text` будет равно результату вызова функции `anotherFunction()`. Т. е. если она например вернула строку `world`, то и переменная `text` будет содержать в себе эту строку

Comment: Большое спасибо, очень доступно объяснили))

Comment: @AlexandrKorol если ответ вам помог, примите его (серая галочка слева).

Comment: @чистов_n Спасибо, буду знать)

Comment: @AlexandrKorol ну так примите этот ответ!